# Identifying Application from Extension

Tags: operating-system, 32-bit, file-extension

Can we identify an application is how much bit ie 16/32/64 bit from its extension.
.com,.exe,.bin specifies anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no. A quick search came up with this link that might be useful:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913111

Comment: I looked but didn't find anything for Linux.

Comment: Also on UNIX-like systems (including Linux) most executable files don't have extensions, and if they do, they are meaningless